# How do I smooth a subdivided surface?

Tags: mesh

I do not know why it curl. What is happening is clearly visible in the photo. It's a simple thing, but I do not know a dream board.! I'd like to smoothly cut off.

[image]

Comment: You may select your surface in Edit Mode and hit **W > smooth** _(not "shade smooth")_, or you can do a complete retopology of the mesh in order to have it low-poly, which will give you more control on surfaces.

Comment: It looks like you subdivided the mesh in Edit mode which leaves the surface heavily faceted because there is no interpolation between the edges that are being filled in.  I find it works best to use a Subdivision modifier and then apply it.  That should give you a much smoother surface.

Comment: BTW:  This looks like an obvious case of Google Translate mangling the words used.  Google cannot handle colloquialism at all-> a figure of speech becomes literal and meaningless. (but I do not know a dream board) :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is to build this mesh again. Here is my solution on how to do it properly:

1. Add a low poly (8 vertices for example) cylinder and subdivide it as many times you like verticaly/ horizontaly.

[image]

2. Select single edge and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>--> Cursor to Selected.

[image]

3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and move the cursor from left to right (or input a value 1). It will make the edge spherical.

[image]

4. Repeat the proces with other edge loops. Select the next one and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Make all of them spherical and then cut the holes.

[image]

5. Delete half of the cylinder and scale it in y axis using *proportional editing*. Now all look super smooth.

[image]